# Custom mount point not working on puppet

Tags: puppet

I'm running Puppet 2.7.14 on RHEL 6.2 (both master and nodes have this configuration).

For the life of me, I can't figure out why I can't make custom mount points work.

If for example, I edit /etc/puppet/fileserver.conf to include the following:

```
[foo]
    path /etc/puppet/files/foo
    allow *
```

And put the file bar.txt in /etc/puppet/files/foo/bar.txt

Then I would expect resources like the following to resolve with no trouble:

```
file { "bar.txt":
    ensure => present,
    path => "/var/foo/bar.txt",
    source => "puppet:///foo/bar.txt",
}
```

But this doesn't work!  I consistently see error messages like the following:

```
... Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///foo/bar.txt ...
```

According to all documentation I have read, I have done this correctly, but I just can't get it to work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there's a "gotcha" at work here.  A tabstop before the path or allow attribute is not allowed.  Very surprising.